# Android Room database ViewModel does not reflect synchronously inserted data

Tags: android, android-room

I am having an issue where data that is written to my Room database does not appear in a ViewModel even though I am writing it synchronously.

This is what a log would look like:

```
com.widget D/WriteActivity: Writing widget data to the database
com.widget D/WriteActivity: Starting the ReadActivity
com.widget D/ReadActivity: Got a new list of 0 objects
```

Here is the situation:

I have two activities, `WriteActivity` and `ReadActivity`. Inside of the `ReadActivity` I have a `ViewModel` listening for database changes (that is instantiated in the `onCreate` method of the Activity):

```
    // observe the widget data
    WidgetViewModel widgetViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(
            WidgetViewModel.class);
    widgetViewModel.getAllWidgets().observe(this, new Observer<List<Widget>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Widget> updatedWidgets) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Got a new list of " + updatedWidgets.size() + " objects");
        }
    });
```

Inside of the `WriteActivity` I have code that adds an object to the database on a background thread, then, once it completes, it launches the `ReadActivity`:

```
    // persist the objects to the room database (doInBackground)
    WidgetRepository myObjectRepository = new WidgetRepository(getApplication());
    myObjectRepository.insert(myObjects); // myObjects is a list of 5 objects

    // load the ReadActivity (onPostExecute)
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(WriteActivity.this, ReadActivity.class);
    WriteActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Here is my DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface WidgetDao {

     @Query("SELECT * FROM widget_table")
     LiveData<List<Widget>> getAll();

     @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     void insert(Widget... widgets);
}
```

My Database:

```
@Database(entities = {Widget.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WidgetDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WidgetDao widgetDao();

    private static volatile WidgetDatabase INSTANCE;

    static WidgetDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {

        if (null == INSTANCE) {
            synchronized (WidgetDatabase.class) {
                if (null == INSTANCE) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WidgetDatabase.class, "widget_database")
                        .build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
public class WidgetRepository {

    private final WidgetDao widgetDao;
    private final LiveData<List<Widget>> widgets;

    public WidgetRepository(Application application) {
        WidgetDatabase db = WidgetDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        widgetDao = db.widgetDao();
        widgets = widgetDao.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Widget>> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }

    public void insert(List<Widget> widgetsToInsert) {
        widgetDao.insert(widgetsToInsert.toArray(
                new Widget[widgetsToInsert.size()]));
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class WidgetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

        private final LiveData<List<Widget>> widgets;

        public WidgetViewModel (Application application) {
            super(application);
            WidgetRepository widgetRepository = new WidgetRepository(application);
            widgets = widgetRepository.getWidgets();
        }

        public LiveData<List<Widget>> getAllWidgets() { return widgets; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. It's embarassing... when I asked my question  I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how LiveData works. RTFM jeez :)

After I read the documentation I came to a stunning revelation: LiveData is tied to the lifecycle of the activity. In the example I gave I was attempting to access the ViewModel during the `onResume` of my `ReadActivity` because I was wanted to make sure that the UI updated properly. Rookie mistake. Like a fool I believed that the Observer callback would only fire when the data encapsulated by the LiveData was modified. In reality, the LiveData callback in the Observer is called when the activity becomes active regardless of whether the data has changed, so there is no need to try to do anything in the `onResume` lifecycle method manually. Just wait for the `onChanged` callback of the Observer and update the UI at that time.

App is working great now, thank you to everyone who read my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that **`LiveData<List<Widget>>`** is not being notified.

So, how to update that ?

see below,

> **Update LiveData objects**
>
> `LiveData` has no publicly available methods to update the stored data.
>   The `MutableLiveData` class exposes the `setValue(T)` and `postValue(T)`
>   methods publicly and you must use these if you need to edit the value
>   stored in a `LiveData` object. Usually `MutableLiveData` is used in the
>   ViewModel and then the ViewModel only exposes immutable LiveData
>   objects to the observers.

So, changes you can make to your **`ViewModel`**:

```
public class WidgetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<Widget>> widgets = new MutableLiveData<List<Widget>>(); // Make it mutable livedata

    public WidgetViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        WidgetRepository widgetRepository = new WidgetRepository(application);
        //widgets = widgetRepository.getWidgets();
        //use this to update your live data instead,
        widgets.setValue(widgetRepository.getWidgets().getValue()); // This will update your live data, use like this for future updates.
    }

    public LiveData<List<Widget>> getAllWidgets() { return widgets; 
}
}
```

Checkout more from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I edited my ViewModel exactly as you described and now whenever the `onChanged` callback in the Observer is called the list of Widgets is always null.